# Oracle APEX 5 Dynamic Action upon page load event does not work. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex-5

The program basically aims at retrieving some fields of a record and processing and displaying that on a textbox of static content region  in apex 5

My database: LCD_MONItOR table

[image]

Interface :

[image]

PLSQL code that is supposed to execute on page load event.

```
   Declare 

   lcd_id   LCD_Monitor.LCD__NO%TYPE;
   tag        LCD_Monitor.ASSET_TAG%TYPE;
   pp      LCD_Monitor.PURCHASE_PRICE%TYPE;
   sal      LCD_Monitor.SALVAGE%TYPE;
   ls       LCD_Monitor.LIFE_SPAN%TYPE;
   accm  LCD_Monitor.ACCUMULATED_DEP%TYPE;
   netbook Number;
   currDep Number;
   Begin
   select LCD__NO, ASSET_TAG, PURCHASE_PRICE,SALVAGE, LIFE_SPAN,
   ACCUMULATED_DEP into lcd_id, tag, pp, sal, ls, accm from LCD_MONITOR 
   where LCD__No='40';

   :LCD_NO:=lcd_id;
   :CURR_DEP:= (pp-sal)*(1/ls);
   :TOT_DEP:= (pp-sal)*(1/ls)+accm;
   :NBV:=pp-(pp-sal)*(1/ls)+accm;

   End;
```

PS: I have returned the values to the textboxes in 'Affected Elements' Section in the properties.

[image]

But when the page is loaded, no values appear in the textboxes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if its `LCD__No` or `LCD_No`. Check there is one additional `_`

Comment: Yes, its LCD__No (double underscore)

Comment: What is the type of your dymanic action? Does user need to send any data to the server for computations?

Comment: Its a page load event and  about the data : No, it is retrieved from the database (LCD_MONITOR Table)

Comment: What is the type of your True Action? True action with the type `Execute PL/SQL Code` hasn't property `Affected Elements`. `Affected Elements` is the property of the action with type `Execute JavaScript Code`. Obviously, that's not what you need.

Comment: The True Action is Set value since I want to set value of the textboxes

Comment: I changed the type to Execute PL/SQL Code, now one of the items' value appear whose value is not calculated but just assigned to the item. I think the problem lies here `:LCD_NO:=lcd_id;:CURR_DEP:= (pp-sal)*(1/ls) :TOT_DEP:= (pp-sal)*(1/ls)+accm;:NBV:=pp-(pp-sal)*(1/ls)+accm;` . Because the first assignment statement executes and displays and the rest dont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly what exactly are you doing. If you need just fill items with data, create a before header process (in Page Designer mode, it is in `Pre-rendering` -> `Before Header`. Write your code there, it should be enough.

If you want to do it in Dynamic Action (I wouldn't recommend this way), you need to create a Dynamic Action with `Event` - `Page Load`, which will contain a True Action with properties: `Action` - `Execute PL/SQL Code`, `PL/SQL Code` - your code and `Items to Return` - `LCD_NO,CURR_DEP,TOT_DEP,NBV`
But make sure your items really have such names, because by default APEX creates items with names like `P10_LCD_NO`, where `10` (for example) is a number of the page.

Comment: No,  Actually I  intend to calculate depreciation from purchase price (table record) of LCD and then display it on the page item (textbox). And yes i have done the same way you are telling for dynamic action but it does not display any value

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly assigning a calculated value to the textfields items, I assigned them to a variable first then assigned variables to the items i.e

Before

```
   :CURR_DEP:= (pp-sal)*(1/ls);
   :TOT_DEP:= (pp-sal)*(1/ls)+accm;
   :NBV:=pp-(pp-sal)*(1/ls)+accm;
```

Corrected

```
    currDep:= (pp-sal)*(1/ls);
    :CURR_DEP:= currDep;
    tot:= (pp-sal)*(1/ls)+accm;
    :TOT_DEP:=tot;
    netbook:=pp-((pp-sal)*(1/ls)+accm);
    :NBV:=netbook;
```